# SFCC - Custom Controller and oAuth

Tags: oauth2, commerce-cloud, node-salesforce

I am creating a custom controller for  a SFCC Commerce Cloud store.

Because I need to have communication with Third-party systems, I created a custom REST API controller to be able to receive some data inside the SFCC.

For a simple controller as the example bellow, how can I use a Oauth authentication as used in the controllers provided by default in OCAPI?

My controller:

```
server.post('Test', server.middleware.https, function (req, res, next) {
    
    //Some logic that should be protected...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the **services framework** for external requests.

**1 - Define your services**

In the **services.xml** file which is part of the metadata to be imported into your site, define your services. Example of services.xml file:

```
    <!-- Service  -->
    <service service-id="your.service.id">
        <service-type>HTTP</service-type>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <log-prefix/>
        <comm-log-enabled>false</comm-log-enabled>
        <profile-id>your.service.profile.id</profile-id>
        <credential-id>your.service.credential.id</credential-id>
    </service>

    <!-- Service credentials -->
    <service-credential service-credential-id="your.service.credential.id">
        <url>https://url-to-your-api</url>
        <user-id>user_id</user-id>
        <password>user_password</password>
    </service-credential>

    <!-- Service profile -->
    <service-profile service-profile-id="your.service.profile.id">
        <timeout-millis>10000</timeout-millis>
        <rate-limit-enabled>false</rate-limit-enabled>
        <rate-limit-calls>0</rate-limit-calls>
        <rate-limit-millis>0</rate-limit-millis>
        <cb-enabled>false</cb-enabled>
        <cb-calls>0</cb-calls>
        <cb-millis>0</cb-millis>
    </service-profile>
```

This can also be done via the admin but I find it easier to work with XML files.

**2 - Register the services in your project**

Create a **services.js** file somewhere in your project. For example, **in scripts/services.js**. Put the following content and adjust to your needs:

```
    'use strict';

    /* API Includes */
    var LocalServiceRegistry = require('dw/svc/LocalServiceRegistry');

    /**
     * Your service wrapper.
     */
    var wrapper = {
        /**
         * Initialize HTTP service.
         * @returns {Object} The service instance
         */
        initMyService: function() {
            return LocalServiceRegistry.createService('your.service.id', {
                createRequest: function(svc, args) {
                    // Prepare the http service
                    // You can access http headers like below - See doc for more
                    svc.addHeader('Authorization', 'your_authorization_header');
                    svc.addHeader('User-Agent', 'your_authorization_header');
                    svc.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');

                    return (args) ? JSON.stringify(args) : null;
                },

                parseResponse: function(svc, resp) {
                    return JSON.parse(resp.text);
                },
            });
        },
    };

    /**
     * Module exports
     */
    module.exports = wrapper;
```

This code will basically register the services defined in the xml file.

**3 - Finally, you can call services**

In order to perform an external HTTP request with your new service, use code similar to the below:

```
    // Load your service class
    var service = require('~/cartridge/scripts/services/myService');

    // Create an instance of your service 
    var serviceInstance = service.initMyService();

    // Prepare request data
    var requestData = {
        /* Optional parameters for the request */
    };

    // Get the result of the HTTP request
    var result = serviceInstance.call(requestData);

    // Response from your external API
    // console.log(result);
```

This is a ***short*** summary of the steps to follow.
Fortunately, the API doc is extremely well detailed and quite comprehensive. Good luck and happy trailblazing!

**EDIT - ADDITIONAL INFO**

1 - Create an external API for your custom authentication logic, separated from the SFCC app. You can use whichever tech you prefer for this, no impact on the SFCC app.

2 - Then from your SFCC controller, check if the user is valid by calling your external custom authentication API. You could for example handle the user login status using a session variable. The session variable can be checked in all scripts/pages you want restricted.

The service logic provided above will just allow you to perform remote authentication to a third party API efficiently and safely.

Also, decoupling the apps will probably make dev and maintenance much easier.

The internal SFCC authentication system will restrict scripts and pages requiring login. So if you want to use the core login system to protect your pages, the advantage is indeed that you don't have to build custom authentication logic and deal with permissions. In this case, just make sure your controller is accessible only for SFCC logged in users + specific permissions and user group restrictions.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, but my question is not about how to call a service from another provider, but to implement a service in my own Commerce Cloud. That is, provide an authenticated controller inside my own Commerce Cloud.

Comment: SFCC has its own internal authentication system. If you need a custom authentication system, it will have to be an external service. In your case, you will just have to build the external service as a separate API, instead of putting the code in your app. Maybe I'm missing elements about your context, but the logic above shouldn't be a hindrance. It's just a shift in the approach. Note that OCAPI offers an API for authentication via the core.

Comment: If you store sensitive authentication or user data in custom SFCC apps, you might have issues reaching production or the market place. See SFCC security standards and GDPR regulation.

Comment: I am creating an endpoint inside the SFCC to update some data. From what I was able to find, the OCAPI only protects their own api endpoints, so if you are creating a custom API entry in your system you will need to provide a custom authentication. I was looking for some JWT exchange using the OCAPI to authenticate and after a token validation, but OCAPI doesn't have a token validation resource either.